# Vim opens with with value pre-entered in command line

Tags: vim

Every time I open a file in vim, :95;c is always pre-typed. I'm not sure why this has started happened lately. Here is a link to my .vimrc: https://github.com/bsiddiqui/vimrc

[image]

Comment: Try to narrow it down. Is it something in your vimrc? Or something in a plugin? type `vim -u NONE` to run without your vimrc. type `vim --noplugin` to run without plug ins.

Comment: running without my vimrc worked but I don't see what changes in my vimrc would cause this

Comment: @bsiddiqui I'm using the same keymaps as yours and having the same problem. Could you explain how did you solve this problem?

Comment: @LVarayut the accepted answer shows the offending lines. To fix I switched from removing search highlighting with escape to remove with return: `nnoremap <CR> :noh<CR><CR>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the offending lines in your vimrc.

```
" remove search highlighting with esc
nnoremap <silent> <esc> :noh<CR><esc>
```

and

```
" ; is better than :, and kj is better than ctrl-c
nnoremap ; :
```

If you remove the first one the behavior goes away. You can keep the second one.

The reason this happens is that vim is trying to use an ANSI escape code to color something. Well the first part of an escape code is escape. It seems that vim consumes its own escape code when it is trying to color something.

An example escape code from wikipedia is `\x1b[30;1m`. `\x` is escape. From here escape gets caught by vim and interpreted. After that the rest of the character are like its typed normally. Then the `;` gets caught and gets reinterpreted as `:` and then `1m` appears on the command line.

I think something similar happened with your vim except with a different escape code.

---

If you want to reproduce it your self you can use the following vimrc file. And run it with `vim -u`

```
set nocompatible
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap <silent> <esc> :noh<CR><esc>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is almost definitely part of an [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). My first guess would be that there's a mismatch between your actual terminal type and what Vim thinks your terminal type is, and it's trying to draw something on the screen that your terminal is misinterpreting.

To see what Vim thinks your terminal is:

```
:set term?
```

To see what your current environment thinks the terminal is:

```
:echo $TERM
```

Ideally, these should match, and should also match whatever terminal you're actually using (but you don't say). If you're using a Linux terminal (e.g. gnome-terminal), or Terminal.app or iTerm2 in OSX, `xterm-256color` is a good choice. In the case of the two OSX terminals, you may have to manually configure that in preferences. A good vanilla starting point is `xterm`; try that and see if it works.

If you're using a multiplexer like screen or tmux, they also allow you to configure a terminal type. In general, it's best to set it in your terminal emulator and let that setting propagate through to Vim on its own, rather than explicitly configuring it.

Comment: both of those returned xterm-256color and i'm using iterm2